# "Kinetic matrices"

Tags: matrices

I've been wondering for a very long time what properties are know on what I will call "kinetic" matrices, for lack of a proper name. These matrices $k_{ij}$ have the following properties:

- $\forall j\neq i,  k_{ij} \geq 0$
- $ \forall i, \sum_{j} k_{ij} = 0$

These kind of matrices are very common in enzyme kinetics. For instance the [Michaelis-Menten](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Michaelis%E2%80%93Menten_kinetics) equations, arising for instance from the chemical reaction:

$$\mathrm{E + S} \mathop{\rightleftharpoons}^{k_\mathrm{f}}_{k_\mathrm{b}} \mathrm{ES} \mathop{\to}^{k_\mathrm{cat}} \mathrm{E + P}$$

For this system, the evolution over time of the concentrations of $\mathrm{E}$ and $\mathrm{ES}$ can be deduced from the differential equation:

$$ \dot{\mathbf{x}} = k \mathbf{x} $$

With $\mathbf{x} = (E, ES)$ and $k$ the following matrix:

$$ k = \left(
\begin{array}{cc}
  -k_f s & k_b + k_{cat}\\
  k_f s & -k_b - k_{cat}\\
\end{array}
\right)
$$

There are a few (more or less) obvious properties, such as:

- they are not invertible;
- their eigenvalues have negative real parts;
- the eigenvalues that are not $0$ have eigenvectors with sums of coefficients equal to $0$.

I'm sure these matrices have been heavily studied before, I just don't seem to find how they are called, and where to learn more about them. What is known about them ?

Comment: These are [transition rate matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transition_rate_matrix), which are used to describe [continuous time Markov chains](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous-time_Markov_chain). Your second property is incorrectly stated: $k_{ii}$ is not equal to $\sum_{j\ne i} k_{ij}$, it has the opposite sign.

Comment: @ Rahul Thanks ! I've edited the post that is now correct. Any good pointer about their properties ?